# C# GODOT | ERROR: call_build: An EditorPlugin build callback failed

Tags: c#, game-physics, godot

```
    Mono: Logfile is: C:\Users\Yunus Aka\AppData\Roaming/Godot/mono/mono_logs/2020_08_12 04.29.52 (13092).txt
Unicode error: invalid skip
ERROR: call_build: An EditorPlugin build callback failed.
   At: editor/editor_node.cpp:5273
```

Hi, i've been start godot and iam taking this error.

I  am using mono godot 64 bit and i already download ".NET framework 4.7.1", ".NET framework 4.7" but it doesn't work. Give me same error again.

Please help meee

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for an error at editor/editor_node.cpp:5273 when I looked at the error and the pressed the "view log" there. It said that I was missing .NET developer pack 4.7.

I tried 4.8 first which didn't work. It had to be 4.7.